# What is the difference between new template site and framework of Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I was going through the web and came across two commands to install Laravel but the directory structure and functionality of the both seemed different. The commands being.

- `composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.2.15 your-project-name --prefer-dist`
- `composer require laravel/framework:5.2.15`

What is the use of the above mentioned commands and how do they differ from each other?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: All I could figure out was that first one installed a website template which I could run and check but I dont know the use of the second one.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Can you please tell me whats the next step after I use `composer require laravel/framework:5.2.15` towards making a web app?